# PTrace Not Recognizing Child Process

Tags: c, linux, x86, ptrace

I'm writing a program that monitors system calls ( among other things ). But I'm having some trouble getting ptrace to recognize the process ID that I'm passing to it. Upon executing the program, I get this error message:

```
:No such process
```

However, I have verified the process ID right before the call by printing it to the console and verifying it with `ps -all`.

Here's some of the code that may be relevant ( I can post more if necessary ):

Heading the child process:

```
/* Call to be traced */

if (ptrace (PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0) < 0){
   perror ("Process couldn't be traced");
   exit (-1);
}

/* Execute process image */

if (execv (ProcessArgs[0], &ProcessArgs[1]) < 0){
    perror ("Couldn't execute process");
    exit (-1);
}
```

In a thread of the parent process:

```
DbgdProcess * _Process = ( DbgdProcess * ) _ProcessPass;

int SystemCall = 0,
        Status = 0;

/* I have tried sleep(1) here to wait for PTRACE_ME to no avail */

while (!_Process->CloseSignal){
    if ( wait  (&Status) < 0) // error handler
    if ( WIFEXITED  (Status)) // error handler
    if (!WIFSTOPPED (Status)) continue;

    SystemCall = ptrace (PTRACE_PEEKUSER, _Process->ID, 4 * ORIG_RAX, 0);

    if (SystemCall < 0) // error handler

    printf ("Process made system call %d\n", SystemCall);

    if (ptrace (PTRACE_CONT, _Process->ID, 0, 0) < 0) // error handler
}
```

May anyone explain this behavior to me?

Some extra notes:

- The process being debugged is a direct child of the parent
- I'm pretty sure this is a 64 bit compilation because sys/reg.h only defines RAX
- All error handlers include a perror() message

**Update:**

I've read this from the man page:

> Most ptrace commands (all except PTRACE_ATTACH, PTRACE_SEIZE,
>   PTRACE_TRACEME, PTRACE_INTERRUPT, and PTRACE_KILL) require the tracee
>   to be in a ptrace-stop, otherwise they fail with ESRCH.

ESRCH, I believe, gives the message 'No such process'. So maybe the process is not ptrace-stopped when I make the ptrace call?

**Update:**

I was testing the code in this [example](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6100). I did getting it to work after doing the following: 
 - updating the header from  to  a
 - changing (eax_orig * 4) to (rax_orig * 8)

But those changes are, as well, in my program and it's still not working.

**Update:**

I've got my code working. I'm not entirely sure why but it started working after I called PTRACE_ATTACH within the same thread that makes the polling calls with ptrace(2). I guess that would mean that ptrace must be used within the same thread of the parent process but I'm not entirely sure. My question now is, does anyone know if that's true? Or, if not, why ptrace behaves this way?

**Update:**

I found this [link](https://gforge.inria.fr/tracker/?func=detail&atid=830&aid=2289&group_id=69), which seems to suggest my problem is not unheard of.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing a PTRACE_SYSCALL, prior to checking if process has stopped or not?

Ideally, in the parent thread, you should wait for child to stop by using wait.

Once the child stops with WIFSTOPPED, then only use any other ptrace calls.

it appears that ESRCH is being returned by PTRACE_SYSCALL. Can you please confirm it

Comment: I've updated my answer, yes I believe ESRCH is the error I'm getting

Comment: Why do you have this line -if (!WIFSTOPPED (Status)) continue;???
Parent should be blocked till it receives signal from child.

Comment: I thought that it would ensure that the process is stopped before calling ptrace. In any case, I think I've found the problem (I've updated my question).

Answer (score 0):

sleep(1) is sometimes not enough; try sleep(5).